# What is the ultimate etymology of "false"?

Tags: etymology, latin

The first two are based on wiktionary

> [***false***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/false#Etymology)
>
> From Middle English **false**, from Old English **fals** (“false, fraud, falsehood”), from Latin **falsus** (“counterfeit, false; falsehood”), perfect passive participle of **fallō** (“deceive”).
>
> Uncommon before the 12 century, the word was reinforced in Middle English by Norman fals (compare Old French faus), eventually displacing native Middle English les, lese (“false”), from Old English lēas; See lease, leasing.
>   For spelling, the -e (on -lse) is so the end is pronounced /ls/, rather than /lz/ as in falls, and does not change the vowel (‘a’). Compare else, pulse, convulse.
>
> [***fallo***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fallo#Latin)
>
> From Proto-Indo-European ***gʰwel-** (“to lie, deceive”). Cognate with Ancient Greek φῆλος (phẽlos, “deceitful”), Sanskrit वृ (vṛ, “twist, crook”), Avestan  (zurah, “injustice”), Lithuanian ẑulas (“rough”), Latvian zvel'u (“to turn aside”), Old Church Slavonic зълъ (zŭlŭ, “evil”)

But here is another etymology from myEtymology.com

> [***false***](http://www.myetymology.com/english/false.html)
>
> the English word false
>
> derived from the Latin word **falsus** (wrong, lying, fictitious)
>
> derived from the Latin word **fallere** (deceive; slip by; disappoint)
>
> derived from the Latin word **facere** (to make; act, take action, be active; compose, write; classify; do, make; create; make, build, construct; produce; produce by growth; bring forth)
>
> derived from the Proto-Indo-European root ***dhē-**

The third etymology is from etymonline.

> [***false***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=false&searchmode=none)
>
> late 12c., from O.Fr. **fals, faus** (12c., Mod.Fr. faux) "false, fake, incorrect, mistaken, treacherous, deceitful," from L. **falsus** "deceived, erroneous, mistaken," **pp. of fallere** "deceive, disappoint," **of uncertain origin (see fail)**. Adopted into other Germanic languages (cf. Ger. falsch, Du. valsch, Dan. falsk), though English is the only one in which the active sense of "deceitful" (a secondary sense in Latin) has predominated. False alarm recorded from 1570s. Related: Falsely; falseness.
>
> [***fail***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fail&allowed_in_frame=0)
>
> early 13c., from O.Fr. **falir** (11c., Mod.Fr. faillir) "be lacking, miss, not succeed," from V.L. ***fallire**, from L. **fallere** "to trip, cause to fall;" figuratively "to deceive, trick, dupe, cheat, elude; fail, be lacking or defective."
>
> Related: Failed; failing. Replaced O.E. abreoðan. The noun (e.g. without fail) is from late 13c., from O.Fr. faile "deficiency," from falir. The Anglo-French form of the verb, failer, came to be used as a noun, hence failure.

I just don't know which PIE form of "false" is the right one.

Comment: You might find [this information](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=false&searchmode=none) helpful (or, maybe it just muddies the water even more). Either way, that website can be a good resource for these kinds of questions.

Comment: @J.R. Thnaks!I will add it to the question.

Comment: @archenoo, which IE languages do you know?

Comment: @AlexB. I know English(as a second language) and a little about others, namely, Latin(just know about the case and declension system), Greek(with an unfinished textbook), German(a layman but willing to continue), Russian(only the alphabet).I am interested in these languages ,especially the connections among them, because they are all daughter languages from one ancestor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked you which IE languages you know - in order to critically evaluate these three hypotheses, a strong background in the history of Latin (at least) is necessary. There are three major textbooks on the history of Latin - [Baldi 1999](http://www.degruyter.com/viewbooktoc/product/47839), [Sihler 1995](http://www.oup.com/us/catalog/general/subject/ClassicalStudies/ClassicalLanguages/?view=usa&ci=9780195083453), and [Weiss 2009](http://www.beechstave.com/weiss.htm).

The first hypothesis is best supported by evidence - and, in fact, pretty standard now (for example, [de Vaan 2008](http://www.brill.com/etymological-dictionary-latin)).

The Anlaut (word-initial) PIE *gwh> Lat. f sound correspondence is well documented, cf. Latin formus 'warm' - MnE warm; Greek thermos; Rus. zhar 'heat', goret' 'burn' etc. We still don't really know how PIE *gwh turned into Latin f (via *χw?) but this correspondence is regular.

We may ignore the perfectum fefelli because it's a relatively new coinage (double ll), cf. pello-pepuli, fero-tetuli ([Meiser 1998](http://www.wbg-wissenverbindet.de/WBGShop/php/Proxy.php?purl=/wbg/products/show,15393.html)), although reduplicated perfectum is usually archaic/rare in Latin.

The second "hypothesis" does not stand to scrutiny - supposedly, Latin fallo is derived from Latin facio. The person who came up with that hypothesis doesn't know Latin morphology at all. I don't know of any rule of Latin word-formation that could explain such a connection.

The third hypothesis does not have any explanation - it stops at Latin fallo.

Answer (score 11):

Here's the OED's etymology:

> Etymology:  late Old English fals adj. and n., < Latin fals-us false
>   (neuter fals-um , used subst. in sense fraud, falsehood), originally
>   past participle of fallĕre to deceive; compare Old Norse fals n. The
>   adj. is found in Old English only in one doubtful instance (see sense
>   A. 13); its frequent use begins in the 12th cent., and was probably
>   due to a fresh adoption through the Old French fals, faus (modern
>   French faux = Provencal fals, Spanish, Portuguese, Italian falso). The
>   continental Germanic languages adopted the word in an altered form:
>   Middle High German valsch, modern German falsch (compare Old High
>   German gifalscôn to falsify), Old Frisian falsch, Dutch valsch, late
>   Icelandic (15th cent.) falskr, Danish, Swedish falsk.
>
> The etymological sense of Latin falsus is ‘deceived, mistaken’ (of
>   persons), ‘erroneous’ (of opinions, etc.). The transition to the
>   active sense ‘deceitful’ is shown in phrases like falsa fides ‘breach
>   of trust, faithlessness’, where the n. has a subjective and an
>   objective sense. In mod. English the sense ‘mendacious’ is so
>   prominent that the word must often be avoided as discourteous in
>   contexts where the etymological equivalent in other Germanic languages
>   or in Romanic would be quite unobjectionable. Some of the uses are
>   adopted < French, and represent senses that never became English.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!It contains more details about the history of "false".

Comment: Though no PIE root; the OED doesn't go in for that, since it was pretty speculative in the 19th century. I can't find a PIE root _*ghwel-_ in either Buck or Watkins, and I don't have Pokorny. So we may have to let that one lie until somebody can look it up.

Comment: @JohnLawler, a list of PIE roots based on Pokorny is here http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/PokornyMaster-X.html The dictionary itself is available here http://archive.org/details/indogermanisches01pokouoft

Comment: Thank you, Alex. I hadn't searched for it. And here's what UT reports: [489 _*gu̯hel-_](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/X/P0747.html)  'to want, wish'; [489-90 _*g̑hu̯el-_](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/X/P0748.html) 'to bend, swerve'. You'd think that 'to bend, swerve' would wind up meaning 'false', wouldn't you? But it's actually 'to want, wish', which refers to how we keep deluding ourselves and others by believing our own fantasies.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I think there is a typo on the UT website. In the scanned version (archive.org), Latin fallo is mentioned in the PIE g̑hu̯el-  entry.

Comment: Could be. Either one could work. That's what's tricky about PIE root attribution; after a few millennia of accumulating accidents, any meaning can get to be any other meaning, by accident.